# Extract Path from shortcut link - windows batch

Tags: batch-file

How can I extract the path from a shortcut link in windows batch file without using vbscript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with a `wmic` query to [win32_shortcutfile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394438%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Just make sure all your backslashes are backslash-escaped within `%filename%`.

Syntax:

```js
batfile shortcutfile.lnk
```

Code:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

rem // ensure user supplied a filename with a .lnk extension
if /i "%~x1" neq ".lnk" (
    echo usage: %~nx0 shortcut.lnk
    goto :EOF
)

rem // set filename to the fully qualified path + filename
set "filename=%~f1"

rem // get target
for /f "delims=" %%I in (
    'wmic path win32_shortcutfile where "name='%filename:\=\\%'" get target /value'
) do for /f "delims=" %%# in ("%%~I") do set "%%~#"

rem // preserve ampersands
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo(!target!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [shortcutjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/shortcutJS.bat)

```
call shortcutjs.bat "some.lnk"^| find /i "target:"
```

Like vbscript this also uses windows script host , but with the other built-in language - jscript , but wrapped in a `.bat` file. Extracting the target will be not possible with pure batch.