# Get the directory of shortcut to a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script file `C:\scripts\MyScript.bat`, I create shortcuts for this file in many other directories:

- folderA\shortcut1.lnk
- folderB\shortcut2.lnk
- ....

I want to be able to get the folder of the shortcut inside the script, meaning if the script called using *shortcut1* I get **folderA**, if using *shortcut2* I get **folderB**, ...

Please note that I can do this without shortcuts, by creating another script *shortcut.bat* and inside this I pass `%~dp0` as a parameter to **MyScript.bat**, but I want to do it with shortcuts because it's easier to manage.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

PS: this is different from the [Extract Path from shortcut link - windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210443/extract-path-from-shortcut-link-windows-batch)
question.

as a user commented below, **I want a batch file which can programmatically determine the location of the shortcut which invoked it**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extract Path from shortcut link - windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210443/extract-path-from-shortcut-link-windows-batch)

Comment: Are you hoping for a batch file which can programmatically determine the location of the shortcut which invoked it?

Comment: @Compo yes exactly, that's what I want

Comment: and it is different from what @GerhardBarnard claim to be duplicate, in that example the shortcut is passed as a parameter to the batch file

Comment: Take a look at two of your shortcuts, and you tell us what differences there are between them!

Comment: the only difference I see is the Location (In general tab of properties) which indicate the folder where the shortcut is located, and this is what I want to get

Comment: If there are no differences, then there's nothing to define one from the other! Have you tried setting the working directory on each shortcut to their existing locations. _Your batch file might then be able to read its current working directory?_

Comment: I have changed the working directory but I am not able to get this information from the target script file (tried %dp, %f, ..). About difference, there is a difference between the two shortcuts, it is their path.

Comment: Interesting request, though I can't imagine what use it will be. I don't see how it would help you manage anything. Either way, I don't think it is possible for a batch script to determine the path of any arbitrary shortcut that launched it. If it were, I think it would involve a dynamic pseudo environment variable (`%ERRORLEVEL%` and `%CMDCMDLINE%` are two examples). But I have never seen a pseudo variable that could yield the info you are seeking.

Comment: Compo's suggestion is a good one. You can get the current directory via `%CD%` (value normally does not have trailing backslash). But `%CD%` is not the best option as it can be spoofed. A more reliable source is `%__CD__%`, which always has a trailing backslash in the value.

Comment: @dbenham, I've adjusted my answer replacing the `%CD%` variable with the more robust `%__CD__%` variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just tested the method I commented on and it appears to work as I had assumed.

Create the following batch file:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "InvokedFrom=%__CD__:~,-1%"
CD /D "%~dp0"
Echo Your current directory is %__CD__:~,-1%
Echo=
Echo This file was invoked from %InvokedFrom%
Echo=
Pause
```

Now create a shortcut to that batch file.

Right Click on the new shortcut and change the **Start in:** field to **%V**.

Now copy the shortcut to a new location and double click it!

The batch file should open and report the path from where the shortcut was located.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to use a shortcut with a blank 'Start in' field.

Make a shortcut to the script, right-click and choose Properties. Clear the "Start in:" field and save it.

Copy/paste that into the target folder and run it.  %cd% will return \folderA\ instead of "C:\Scripts"